# No such file or directory No top level modules, and no -s option

Tags: macos, verilog, iverilog

I have Icarus Verilog installed on macos, but when I run it in the terminal to get a `.vcd` file, it always give me these messages:

```
ben@Bens-macbook ~ % iverilog -o khanh.vvp khanh_tb.v
khanh_tb.v: No such file or directory
No top level modules, and no -s option.
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Those error messages mean that the input file (`khanh_tb.v`) is not in your current directory.

Either change your current directory to the one where the file is, or run `iverilog` and specify the path to the `.v` file:

```
iverilog -o khanh.vvp path/to/khanh_tb.v
```

`path/to/` is just an example; you should change it to the directory path where the file resides.